# Адаптивный background html css

Tags: html, css, frontend

Что делать если при изменении разрешения фона картинка перестаёт уменьшаться пропорционально экрану и оставляет белое пространство?
Codepen

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kaushan+Script&family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap");
#html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#home_page {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#home_page .section-header {
  background: linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%,
      rgba(0, 255, 247, 0.089) 50%,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%
    ),
    url(https://i.postimg.cc/6pjW079H/231132323231123.png);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #464646;
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
#home_page .logo {
  transform: translate(-200px, 0);
}
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1200px;
}

#home_page .section-header .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#home_page .section-header .container .menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
#home_page .section-header .container .menu a {
  /* здесь был padding  - надо убрать его*/
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

#home_page .section-header .container .menu .item {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#home_page .section-header .container .logo {
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#home_page .section-header .container:nth-child(2) {
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

#home_page .section-header .container:nth-child(2) h2 {
  font-family: Kaushan Script, sans-serif;
  font-size: 4.5rem;
  margin-top: 170px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
@keyframes flicker {
  0%,
  18%,
  22%,
  25%,
  53%,
  57%,
  100% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #00f7ff, 0 0 2px #00f7ff, 0 0 5px #00f7ff,
      0 0 11px #00f7ff, 0 0 20px #00f7ff, 0 0 30px #00f7ff, 0 0 55px #00f7ff,
      0 0 80px #00f7ff;
  }
  20%,
  24%,
  55% {
    text-shadow: none;
  }
}
#home_page .section-header .container:nth-child(2) h1 {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  font-size: 9.375rem;
  margin-top: 65px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: -5px;
  line-height: 140px;
  transform: translate(0, -100px);
  animation: flicker 1.5s infinite alternate;
}

#home_page .section-header .container:nth-child(2) .line {
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transform: translate(0, -100px);
}

#home_page .section-header .container:nth-child(2) .button {
  transition: 0.2s;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border: 8px solid #00f7ff;
  transform: translate(0, -100px);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #00eeffec, 0 0 2px #00eeffd7, 0 0 6px #00eeff,
    0 0 12px #00eeffbe, inset 0 0 1px #00eeffa2, inset 0 0 2px #00eeff86,
    inset 0 0 6px #00eeff60, inset 0 0 12px #00eeff33;
}

#home_page .section-header .container:nth-child(3) {
  color: white;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
}

#home_page .section-header .container:nth-child(3) .row {
  margin-top: 100px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#home_page .section-header .container:nth-child(3) .row .col-3 {
  width: 23%;
}
#home_page .section-header .container .hhh {
  scale: 20%;
}

#home_page .section-header .container:nth-child(3) .row .col-3 .line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#home_page .section-header .container:nth-child(3) .row .col-3 .text {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}

#home_page .section-header .container:nth-child(3) .row .col-3 .text h2 {
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

#home_page .section-header .container:nth-child(3) .row .col-3 .text h3 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Главная</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/styles/style.css">
</head>

<body id="home_page">
      <div class="section-header">
            <div class="container">
                  
                  

            </div>

            <div class="container">
                  <div class="text-block">
                        <h2 class="kaushan"></h2>
                        <h1> Welcome </h1>
                  </div>         
                  <a href="#vvs" class="button">
                        Learn 
                  
                  </a>
            </div>

            <div class="container">
                  <div class="row">
                  </div>
            </div>

      </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: картинка-то как раз уменьшается пропорционально экрану, а вот белое поле - это результат горизонтального скролла, потому что Вы задали контейнеру фиксированную ширину в 1200px. сделайте max-width вместо width (а для экранов меньше 900px уменьшите размер надписи, чтобы она не вылезала за края экрана)